# Почему string::find ведёт себя по разному

Tags: c++

Есть код

```
bool check_tape(char* tape) {
    int test8; 
    cout << example <<" "<<example.size()<<" "<<alpha_sym<<" "<< endl;
    cin >> test8; //Чтобы приостановить программу, сделано тоже временно
    int err = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < example.size(); i++) {
        if (alpha_sym.find(example[i]) >= 0 && alpha_sym.find(example[i]) < example.size()) {
            cout << alpha_sym.find(example[i]) << " " << endl;
            err += 0;
        }
        else {
            cout << example[i]<<" "<< i << " не содержится в алфавите" << endl;
            err++;
        }
    }
    if (err) {
        return 1; //Временно сделан возврат 1, чтобы не прерывалась программа
        //get_acmd();
    }
    else return 1;
}
```

Проблема в том, что в одном случае find возвращает позицию первого вхождения, а в другом сам символ, который искался в строке.
111+11 - строка, символы из которого ищутся в 1+_
Так же и с 1435+212, символы из которого ищутся в 01234567+_

[image: Нормальный случай]

[image: Странный случай]

Comment: if (alpha_sym.find(example[i]) >= 0 && alpha_sym.find(example[i]) < example.size()) Вы уверены, что сравнивать надо с example.size()? Не с alpha_sym.size()?

Comment: у вас в консоли хороший вопрос. Действительно, что вы хотите делать?.. Ничего не понятно, ни ход ваших мыслей, ни исходные данные, ни желанный результат

Comment: Какой тип имеют `alpha_sym`, `example`??? Из заголовка вопроса, наверное, можно догадаться, но здесь не место для догадок. Почему в коде отсутствуют объявления этих объектов? И где вы увидели, что "find возвращает сам символ, который искался в строке"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не ясно почему вдруг в

```
if (alpha_sym.find(example[i]) >= 0 && alpha_sym.find(example[i]) < example.size())
```

делается сравнение с `example.size()`. Также, результат `std::string::find` имеет *беззнаковый* тип. Поэтому не ясно, что здесь делает сравнение `>= 0` и какой смысл вы в него вкладывали.

Не ясно также, с чего вы взяли, что у вас где-то "find возвращает сам символ, который искался в строке". Ничего подобного, разумеется, не происходит.

В случае неудачного поиска функция `std::string::find` возвращает значение `std::string::npos`. Вот на него и надо проверять, а не изобретать какие-то свои способы проверки.

---

И что за манера вызывать одну и ту же относительно "тяжелую" функцию несколько раз с одними и теми же параметрами?